# Is it possible to display a single image bigger when our website is viewed on a mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

We have a login button showing at the top right of our page "Customer login".

Is it possible to make this image bigger **only** when the site is viewed on a mobile phone?

Clearly in an ideal world we'd have a whole mobile version of our site created, however this is unfeasible at this moment.

If it helps our site can be viewed - [here](http://www.workbooks.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries for that:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){ /* for ipad and below */
  img{width: 100%;max-width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Will this work with a single image? How do I apply it to one image?

Comment: give that image a class and apply the css for that class.

Comment: As in give the image the media class?